# how to make armadillo-5.200.1 (+openblas or lapacke) work with visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have been trying to make armadillo-5.200.1 and openblas (or lapacke) work with visual studio 2010 since a week now and I still have several unresolved external symbols errors with functions from the blas and lapack libraries.
First, I tried to install openblas from pre-built binaries for windows and set up a new project and test it with the sample code below:

```
#include <cblas.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    blasint n = 10;
    blasint in_x =1;
    blasint in_y =1;

    std::vector<double> x(n);
    std::vector<double> y(n);

    double alpha = 10;

    std::fill(x.begin(),x.end(),1.0);
    std::fill(y.begin(),y.end(),2.0);

    cblas_daxpy( n, alpha, &x[0], in_x, &y[0], in_y);

    //Print y
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        std::cout << y[j] << "\t";

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I got an unresolved external symbol « cblas_daxpy » error. I tried to build the same project with code::blocks and got the same error.

I downloaded and set up msys to be able to compile the source I downloaded on github (https://github.com/xianyi/Openblas) and tried to make it work both on code::blocks and visual studio, but I still got the same errors.

Then I tried on my own laptop, because it has Linux ubuntu 14.04 LTS. So, I cloned the github and compiled the sources and tried to set it up in another code::blocks project and I test it using the same sample code and got undefined reference errors concerning functions such as pthread_create and pthread_join.

I also tried to compile lapacke sources with cmake, following the instructions of the following page : https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/. I used the example, to test, the project built correctly, but when I execute the programm I have an pop-up window message saying that the liblapacke.dll can't be find.

To use openblas with visual studio, I followed the instructions about third-party library:

```
add the location of the header files to "C/C++->Additional Include Directories"
add the .lib files to the "Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies"
add the location of the .lib files to "Linker->General->Additional Library Directories"
```

I need to make this work at least with windows 7 and better with visual studio 2010, because we use it at work.

Answer (score 0):

you should copy dll file to system32 direction or Debug or Release folder of y

Comment: I tried copying it in both Release and Debug folder and compiled the project in each mode but it did not work, copying the file in the system32 direction did not work either.